# How to know HTTP error status in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, http

I'm just upgrading Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.0. In my App/Exception/Handler.php file i have a code like this:

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    ...

    return parent::report($e);
}
```

I want to know how get the error code(500,404,...) of the response in the `report` method.

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   // If this exception is an instance of HttpException
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        // Grab the HTTP status code from the Exception
        $status = $e->getStatusCode();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException)
{
    $e->getStatusCode();
}
```